# Datatables iOS, Safari not showing at all

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, datatables

I tried the library, but I encountered error while testing in Safari. All the tables that work on Chrome, IE and Firefox refuse to work on Safari. Tried searching on the library website, but found no relevant information.
I got 2 variables:

```
var tabl1;
tabl1= $('#tabl1').DataTable(tabl1DataTableArguments);
```

tabl1DataTableArguments holds all the arguments for the table:

```
var tabl1DataTableArguments = {
"dom": "<'row'<'#toolbar1.col-sm-12'>><'row'<'col-sm-4'B><'col-sm-4 text-center'l><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
"<'row'<'#top.col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        title: 'Data',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0]
        }
    },
    {
        extend: 'csvHtml5',
        title: 'Data',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0]
        }
    },
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        title: 'Data',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [0]
        }, customize: function (doc) {
            doc = CustomizeDataTables(doc);
        }
    },
],
"aLengthMenu": [[5, 10], [5, 10]],
"autoWidth": false,
ajax: {
    url: UrlData,
    method: "POST",
    dataSrc: 'Data'
},
columns: [
    {
        "title": "Title",
        data: 'Title', type: "String", width: "80%",
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return "<a href='"+full.id+"'>" + data + "</a> ";
        }

    }
]
}
```

The thing I don't understand is why does it work everywhere else, but in Safari it just dies with no errors or anything. When I try to initialize it through the console it says that it is already initialized.

Comment: which datatable library have u used??? could u resolve?..im facing same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved with the latest version of the library.

Comment: you should mention which version you were using previously and which version resolved the issue.